# How to execute local stored value by search function afther page reload / refresh

Tags: javascript

I use the following form and script to let users filter a td table on the input they give in. It filters the rows of the table and only shows the rows corresponding to their given value. They can update the rows that they are seeing, after they do this the page refreshes/reloads to refresh the table. After the page is refreshed/reloaded the search filter shows all rows again. I am searching for a way to keep the rows that they had before the update event happend based on their filter input. In other words, as if the refresh never happend.

Search form;

```
...

<p align='left' style="display:inline">
  <table class="userprof" align='left'>
    <tr>
      <td class="footer">Filter:
        <input type="text" id="myInput" name="filter" style="color:black !important;" placeholder="Filter table" onkeyup='saveValue(this);' />

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</p>
...
```

I use the folowing script to save their input as localstorage.

```
...

document.getElementById("myInput").value = getSavedValue("myInput"); // set the value to this input 
/* Here you can add more inputs to set value. if it's saved */

//Save the value function - save it to localStorage as (ID, VALUE)
function saveValue(e) {
  var id = e.id; // get the sender's id to save it . 
  var val = e.value; // get the value. 
  localStorage.setItem(id, val); // Every time user writing something, the localStorage's value will override . 
}

//get the saved value function - return the value of "v" from localStorage. 
function getSavedValue(v) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
    return ""; // You can change this to your defualt value. 
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(v);
}

...
```

I use the following script to filter the table rows

```
...

function filterTable(event) {
  var filter = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
  var rows = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody").rows;

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var nameCol = rows[i].cells[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rankCol = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rankerCol = rows[i].cells[5].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var typeCol = rows[i].cells[6].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var emailCol = rows[i].cells[3].textContent.toUpperCase();
    if (nameCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || rankCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || rankerCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || typeCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || emailCol.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      rows[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup', filterTable, false);

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there and only need minor modifications to make this happen.
I'd suggest that you change your flow up a bit.

First remove the `onkeyup` inline listener from your HTML. You are currently listening for that event 3 times on 1 element which seems overkill.

```
...

<p align='left' style="display:inline">
  <table class="userprof" align='left'>
    <tr>
      <td class="footer">Filter:
        <input type="text" id="myInput" name="filter" style="color:black !important;" placeholder="Filter table" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</p>
...
```

Then modify the `filterTable` to accept just a value, not an event object. This way you can call `filterTable` at any time and inject a value into it. And it allows you to call it immediately with the stored value when the page loads so that your initial filter will be set (or not if there is nothing stored).

Now listen for the `keyup` event with only a single listener which will both pass the value of the event to `filterTable` and the event itself to `saveValue` so that are both filtering and saving.

```
// Store the input in a variable for reference.
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
var savedValue = getSavedValue("myInput");

// Immediately filter the table and set the input value.
filterTable(savedValue);
myInput.value = savedValue;

//Save the value function - save it to localStorage as (ID, VALUE)
function saveValue(e) {
  var id = e.id; // get the sender's id to save it . 
  var val = e.value; // get the value. 
  localStorage.setItem(id, val); // Every time user writing something, the localStorage's value will override . 
}

//get the saved value function - return the value of "v" from localStorage. 
function getSavedValue(v) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
    return ""; // You can change this to your default value. 
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(v);
}

function filterTable(value) {
  console.log(value);
  var filter = value.toUpperCase();
  var rows = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody").rows;

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var nameCol = rows[i].cells[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rankCol = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rankerCol = rows[i].cells[5].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var typeCol = rows[i].cells[6].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var emailCol = rows[i].cells[3].textContent.toUpperCase();
    if (nameCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || rankCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || rankerCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || typeCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || emailCol.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      rows[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

myInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  var value = event.target.value;
  saveValue(event);
  filterTable(value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I have changed my codes to above codes to my php file. Now it calls the stored filter when reload and opening page. But it is not posible to change that stored filter. It does not seem to do anything except filtering on the saved value it had in storrage.

Comment: Did you add the `keyup` event handler at the bottom of the script? Could you log if the event handler is being called?

Comment: I coppied the whole code and pasted it as one script. I am a litle new to this. How do i log the event to see if it is called?

Comment: Inside the `function(event) {` function use `console.log(event)` to log the current event object to the console. In the console you can output messages, data and all the values in your script. It's an essential developers tool.

Comment: I get the following errors.

accounts.php:993 Uncaught TypeError: value.toUpperCase is not a function
    at filterTable (accounts.php:993)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Uncaught ReferenceError: filterTable is not defined
    at accounts.php:155

uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at accounts.php:1035

Comment: Okay, that's useful. So first error claims that the `value` passed to `filterTable` is not a string. Strings have the `toUpperCase` function, so check what is being passed to `filterTable`. The second one tells you that `filterTable` does not yet exist at that point, so there is probably a wrong order in your code. The last one tells you that `myInput` has a value of `null` instead of the input element. So that element is either not on the page or the script is trying to select the element before the element even exists. Make sure to check both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As i said i am new to scripts. I have the original ones in the following order. First the html code, than the storrage script. Thanks there is a mysql select to get the values than the table gets populated and after that i had the filter script. In this order it worked fine. 

I now have you code pasted as on script after the table population. So if that is not right how should it be added?

Comment: I have made some changes. Now the only error is accounts.php:1025 Uncaught TypeError: value.toUpperCase is not a function
    at filterTable (accounts.php:1025)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (accounts.php:1046)

You say, check what is passes to filtertable. I dont know what you mean by that.

Comment: Can you help me with that last error? I have googled but i cant find a solution. Its plain text that a user fills in to filter. It worked before it bow doesnt. Any ideas?

Comment: Log the `value` argument in the `filterTable` function. This way you can discover what the value of `value` is and what adjustments need to be made.

Comment: It might be better to create a new post with the error as a new question and make an interactive snippet so the code can be reproduced. That way me and my colleagues can take a look at it. ;)